# PostCSS cannot compile SASS with variable selectors

Tags: webpack, sass, postcss

I am trying to compile a litte sass lib to css using Webpack and PostCSS.

My components are separated in the actual style and a notation file, which provides
all class names of the component. This is because some components are nested and I want to have a central file for the name configuration and do not want to edit X strings in y files.

An example.

`_notation.scss`

```
@use '../../abstracts/variables';
$prefix: variables.$material-prefix;

$button: ".#{$prefix}button";
$button__icon: ".#{$prefix}button__icon";
$button__label: ".#{$prefix}button__label";
```

`_button.scss`

```
@use '../../abstracts/mixins';
@use './notation' as NButton;
@use '../../ripple/notation' as NRipple;

@mixin core-styles(){
    #{NButton.$button}{
        /* Styles */
    }
}

@include core-styles();
```

PostCSS throws an syntax error:

```
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SyntaxError
```

### Simplyfied example:

```
$var: "TEST";

.#{$var} {
}
```

PostCss throws the same error:

```
   6 | $var: "TEST";
   7 | 
>  8 | .#{$var} {
     |    ^
```

Compiling my SASS into CSS without PostCss works fine.
So how can I fix the behavior of PostCss?